# Como puxar dados do XML pela "tag", usando FileReader e DOMparser? (NFe)

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, nfe

### O que estou fazendo de errado?

- Minha intenção é guardar algumas informações de uma NFe(pegar os dados da tag) a partir de um XML, sem ter que fazer **upload** do mesmo em lugar algum.

**Head** -

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**Body** -

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
<h1>-------------</h1>
<p id="demo"></p><br>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo4"></p>
<p id="demo5"></p>
```

**Script** -

```
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Print the contents of the file
          var span = document.createElement('span');                    
          span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e.target.result));
          var parser = new DOMParser();
          var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(span.innerText,"text/xml");
          //document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = xmlDoc;
          document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '1:' + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("infNFe");
          document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = '2:' + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("infNFe")[0];
          document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = '3:' + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("infNFe")[0].childNodes;
          document.getElementById('demo4').innerHTML = '4:' + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("infNFe")[0].childNodes[0];
          document.getElementById('demo5').innerHTML = '5:' +
          xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("infNFe")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

          //Teste criando Append em um span, para testar se ele mostra todo o conteudo do XML
          //document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);
      // Read in the file
      reader.readAsText(f);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

## Após executar tenho esse resultado, utilizando um XML de NFe v4.00

1:[object HTMLCollection]

2:[object Element]

3:[object NodeList]

4:[object Element]

5:null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tem como ir destrinchando um **xml** `<tag>` por `<tag>`, logo o correto é procurar diretamente a `<tag>` que está procurando, e se existir mais de uma, incrementar o `[ ]` do comando, para pular para a próxima `<tag>` com o mesmo nome.

Logo meu objetivo era pegar a versão da nota fiscal e o nome do destinatario, e o que corrigiria isso no código seria:

```
    return function(e) {
      // Print the contents of the file
      var span = document.createElement('span');                    
      span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e.target.result));
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(span.innerText,"text/xml");
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("infNFe")[0].getAttributeNode("versao").value;
      var z = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("xNome")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =  '1:' + x;
      document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = '2:' + z;

    };
```

- Dessa forma, é possível pegar o conteúdo de dentro de uma `<tag>`,
  diretamente.

---

### Se houver outra forma de fazer a mesma coisa, se manifeste, talvez seja mais eficiente do que a que estou utilizando!